# Change cell color based on the top cell number

Tags: excel

I would like to make the cell color change if the value contained in the cell is less than, equal to or greater than the value of the upper cell. I am not very experienced in excel, so I ask you to be "precise". Below I have attached a photo of how it should look like (blue color if the two values are the same, red color if the top cell value is greater than the cell, green color if the top cell value is less than the cell. Thanks a lot in advance!

[image]

↑  Exemple

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the formulas for the conditional formatting in the picture.
Replace semikolon with comma if your Excel version needs it.

Apply the same rules for the second column and change the formulas accordingly.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You need to change the column (A2) to that column where your data is.